# Creating a table using jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, templating-engine

I am trying to create a (latex) table using jinja2. I defined a macro to help me to create the table:

```
{% macro table(header, rows, columns) %}
\begin{tabular}{(formatting, later)}
  {{ row(header) }}
  {% for row in rows %}
    {% for column in columns %}
    {{ caller(row, column) }} & % *here*
    {% endfor %} \\
  {% endfor %}
\end{tabular}
{% endmacro %}
```

I can use the template like this:

```
{% call(row, column) table.table(header, rows, columns) %}
  Content at row = {{row}}, column = {{column}}
{% endcall %}
```

I quite like how these macros work. The problem is however that I would like to `join` the results  of the macro by a `&` sign rather than
playing a sign after each row. Essentially now I have this:

```
    Content at row = 0, column = 0 &
    Content at row = 0, column = 1 & \\
```

and I would like to get this instead:

```
    Content at row = 0, column = 0 &
    Content at row = 0, column = 1 \\
```

Is it possible to use filters on macro results? Is there some other way to generate a table where each cell is another jinja2 template depending on parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a `join` functionality in Jinja itself. However it does have built in indexes on your loop. Using `loop.last` you can determine where to change the output symbol

```
    {% macro table(header, rows, columns, ) %}
    \begin{tabular}{(formatting, later)}
      {{ row(header) }}
      {% for row in rows %}
        {% for column in columns %}
        {{ caller(row, column) }} {% if loop.last %}\\{% else %}&{%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    \end{tabular}
    {% endmacro %}
```

Here's documentation on the other `loop` variables that are available: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for